# Angular Watch Triggered if newValue changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, watch

I want to change value's based on other values in a repeat. I made a watch but the thing is that if i alter the newValue inside the watch the watch is triggered again.

Is there a way to solve this problem

my watch:

```
 $scope.$watch('objlist', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.counter += 1;
    for (var count = 0; count < newValue.length; ++count) {
      if (typeof newValue[count] != "undefined" && (typeof oldValue == "undefined" || newValue[count].value1 != oldValue[count].value1)) {
        newValue[count].value3 = newValue[count].value1 * newValue[count].value2;
        newValue[count].value3 = Number(newValue[count].value3).toFixed(2);

      }
      if (typeof newValue[count] != "undefined" && (typeof oldValue == "undefined" || newValue[count].value3 != oldValue[count].value3)) {
        newValue[count].value1 = newValue[count].value3 / newValue[count].value2;
        newValue[count].value1 = Number(newValue[count].value1).toFixed(2);

      }
    }
  }, true);
```

i have included a plunker to show you what i mean.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w1qNpB0eqZf0PQ898hWw)

as you can see if you change the value of field 1 or 3 it automaticly adds 2 to the counter and sets both to toFixed(2). This makes it hard to edit the fields.

We use angular 1.2.25

Comment: Just a tip but you can replace typeof newValue[count] != "undefined" by just newValue[count] . It should do the same. testing an undefined is the same as saying false

Comment: since you are taking the the last argument as `true` in $watch, this implies the watch is deep object watch. You cannot change the object that is being watched.

Comment: he could add a watch for each element of the list, separated. Not usable of course if he doesn't know the number of element.

Comment: and the number of elements can change so that is not posible unfortunatly

Comment: @Chandermani i know that i deep watch the object but this is needed to detect changes of properties of objects in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small trick with a condition.

For instance :

```
$scope.watchActivated = true;

$scope.$watch('objlist', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( $scope.watchActivated ) {
$scope.watchActivated = false;
   $scope.counter += 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < newValue.length; ++count) {
  if (typeof newValue[count] != "undefined" && (typeof oldValue == "undefined" || newValue[count].value1 != oldValue[count].value1) )
{
   newValue[count].value3 =  newValue[count].value1 * newValue[count].value2;
  newValue[count].value3 = Number(newValue[count].value3).toFixed(2);

}
  if (typeof newValue[count] != "undefined" && (typeof oldValue == "undefined" || newValue[count].value3 != oldValue[count].value3) )
{
     newValue[count].value1 =  newValue[count].value3 / newValue[count].value2;
  newValue[count].value1 = Number(newValue[count].value1).toFixed(2);

}
}
$scope.watchActivated = true;
}
}, true);
```

Far from elegant but it should work. 
Careful the code might not be good I just did a quick edit.

Comment: unfortunatly it does not work. This is because the 2nd watch will not run before the first is done so the watchActivated is always true also for the second time.